# How to remove the network icon from the menu bar?

Tags: icons, macbook, system-settings, menu-bar

I clicked on the WiFi Network symbol in Applications to many times and I now have 8 Network connection icons in my menu bar.  I didn't realize till to late that it was adding them to the menu bar.  I was clicking and waiting for an app to open and when it didn't I clicked again.  Is there a way to get it back to 1 icon ?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: I am running ubuntu 14.0.2

Comment: Describe please what do you click. What is "Applications"? You can make a screenshot and post a link to your question.

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? (If you are not sure, you can look at the screenshot [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available))

Comment: I am using Unity [link] (https://www.anony.ws/image/DQQt)

Comment: and here is what my menu bar looks like [link] (https://www.anony.ws/image/DQQ2)

Comment: And what is the point of starting applications this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all duplicates of the connection icons by killing the `nm-applet` process, like this:

```
$ sudo killall nm-applet
```

Then start a new one with:

```
$ sudo nm-applet &
```

Comment: @skiter I'm glad to here it worked. Please accpet my answer.

Comment: In 15.10 `sudo nm-applet &` didn't bring it back, just press `Alt+F2` and type `nm-tool`.